# taxonomy.php doesn't display images from "../image/" folder

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have some images loading in the header `(header.php)` from the location `"../images/"`

code is

```
<div class="header">
                <img src="../images/headerimg.gif"  alt=""/>

</div>
```

while the pages and custom post type load the image correctly from the location ..

the taxonomy.php doesn't load the image at all instead shows the cross sign which image is there but not loaded

plz help

Answer (score 2):

In wordpress, you should never use such relative paths.

You should use one of the Built-in path functions , like [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/headerimg.gif">
```

or in the event you want to be included or ovverriden by child theme use [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

All this of course assumes that the images are in a sub-folder called `images` under the main theme folder. ( which is how it is supposed to be )

In case that the image is an Uploaded image , it should be referenced by the `ID` or the URL that is supplied from the upload . Even in the case you do not want to do so for some ( probably wrong ) reason , you should then also use wp functions like for example [wp_upload_dir()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir)